# JQuery: find element whose class contains value of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched high and low now but I can't figure out how to get this to work:

**I need to get the element whose class name contains a number that I pass with a variable.**

For better understanding: This is inside a "click" event on a gallery. Whenever an img is clicked I search for the src, see which number the string contains and then want to find the matching p whose class contains the same number. So I can manipulate the matching text to the picture that is currently displayed (Since the plugin I use strips away any id or class I can only identifiy a picture by its source name).

So far it does work if I directly put the number in as a String. Like this:

```
var team_t = $(this).find("img").attr("src");

    for(n = 1; n <=6; n++ ){

            if(team_t.indexOf(n) != -1)
            {   
                $('#text_content').find("p[class*='3']").css("background-color", "red");

            }
    }
```

But instead of "3" I want it to get the number that the variable n holds. I tried this but it did not work:

```
$('#text_content').find("p[class*=' + n + ']").css("background-color", "red");
```

Actually it didn't work with any kind of variable I tried to pass. I also saw and tried examples that use contains( ) or hasClass( ) and others.. but nothing worked for me. I'm not extremly familiar with the syntax though.

How do I have to write this so it takes the variabel as a string?

If I do alert( n ) it shows the correct number, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Gosh. A question clearly laying out the problem and showing an attempt to solve it. I'm ... almost not sure what to do. :-) (Yes, folks, it's a *simple* problem, but it's properly asked, which makes a refreshing change.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were on the right track with string concatenation, you just didn't get all the way outside the string:

```
$('#text_content').find("p[class*='" + n + "']").css("background-color", "red");
// Change is here -----------------^- and -^
```

In your attempt, the `+ n +` was still in the outer quotes, and so was used literally in the selector (making it fail).

---

That said, if you have any control over the DOM structure (but it sounds like you may not), there's probably a better way. For instance, you could put a `data-*` attribute on the element that gives an appropriate selector for the `p` element (possibly even by `id`, but that's just one option).

---

You might also want to end the loop once you've found the index, by putting `break;` on the line after the line setting the red color.

---

Finally: You might want to use a class to add the red color rather than mixing your presentation into your JavaScript code.

Comment: Wow that was really fast ;). Thank you so much! That worked. I knew it was only some little thing that I missed. I tried that befor but I think I used the wrong quotation marks.

For the break and the class/insted css: I incorporated that now, thanks for the advice!

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understood the other thing you wrote. But I guess you mean to use that as an easier way find a match instead of scanning the src of the img for a string?
I think I could put a data attribute to the div holding the img that was just clicked if you mean that. But I don't know how I could match that to a certain p element since all p have different ids but the data attr would always contain the same thing?!  Maybe you could clarify that a bit if that's what you meant. Thanks! =)